# When to use a mapping table

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL, if I have a limited number of `categories` that is never going to change, should I create them as bool fields in the table of the thing they categorise, or should I use a mapping table? If so, why?

---

**Case A:**

t_stuff

```
id (int) 
name (string) 
category_a (bool) 
category_b (bool) 
category_c (bool) 
category_d (bool) 
category_e (bool) 
category_f (bool)
```

---

**Case B:**

t_stuff

```
id (int)
name (string)
```

t_categories

```
id (int)
name (string)
```

t_stuff_category

```
id (int)
stuff_id (int)
category_id (int)
```

---

While A does not look as "nice" as B, it does seem a lot simpler in terms of the query needed?

Edit: I feel that I should add that all I ever need to do is:

- Get all stuff rows
- Get all the stuff rows which have one particular category
- Get one stuff row which has a particular id

Answer (score 3):

Never use case `A`. It violates the principles of relational databases. Learn about [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Let's say you want to find the `id` for `category = 1`, you would need to check each column in case `A`:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   t_stuff
WHERE  category_a = 1 
        OR category_b = 1 
        OR category_c = 1 
        OR category_d = 1 
        OR category_e = 1 
        OR category_f = 1
```

This design not only makes it difficult to query, but it's also a nightmare with aggregation. What if you wanted to get the `COUNT(*)` of categories for a particular `id`?

In case `B`, you would just query a single attribute:

```
SELECT stuff_id 
FROM   stuffCategory
WHERE  category_id = 1
```

To get the `COUNT(*)`, you just replace `id`.

Further, you don't need `id` under `t_stuff_category`. A composite primary key of (`stuff_id, category_id`) would suffice.

Comment: Your case B query doesn't seem to match the design. Also, I never want to find what you mentioned for case A. I either want all rows, or all the rows with one specific category.

Comment: @Ben Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Regarding using a composite primary key, make sure you create a Unique Index / Constraint when creating the table. If you accidentally end up with duplicate rows, and have no auto-incrementing key, deleting the duplicates can be very fiddly.

Comment: Yes, in your case B that's one query. But beforehand you need to get the stuff_id, and afterwards, you still need to get the category information based on the category_id. Makes 3 queries in case B vs 1 query in case A. Or not?

Comment: @Ben If you needed information from more than one table in your result, you would simply use an SQL `JOIN` clause; there would be no need for multiple queries.

Comment: You may never need to use any of the queries in my answer. They are just trying to illustrate the principle of relational databases. Databases are optimized to be relational; when you break the relational design, you'll get poor performance.

Comment: So how is a simple select less performant than a join? My whole point is, in *this* situtation that I am actually dealing with, what is the most performant solution?

Comment: In the first case, the engine will need to check 6 columns vs. 1 column that is probably indexed. Relational databases are based on the principle of set theory.

Comment: @Ben The most permanent and **only** solution here is case B.

Comment: I don't see how the case B solution can offer something more performant than, for example, `SELECT * from t_stuff WHERE category_c = 22`. I might be wrong, but it seems counter-intuitive that a more complicated query involving more than one table would result in less processing than a simple query involving only one table?

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing here is "never say never" - in the question and in comments, you state confidently that:

- the number (and, implicitly, meaning) of categories will **never** change
- you will **never** need to query things like "how many categories is item X in"

Requirements change over time, and designing a system based on predictions that something will **never** happen is likely to lead to frustration later, as you have to work around limitations in your design.

Granted, there are a few advantages to the de-normalised version (with just boolean columns), but really only if you have a very small number of "categories" (I would say <=3) so that you can think of them as "attributes" rather than "categories":

1. Searching for all products in category A OR category B is slightly easier, as you don't have to worry about the effect of the `JOIN` clause if the product is in both.
2. Some queries are a little simpler to write, as you don't need to worry about `JOIN` clauses.

Here are some things you can do with a normalised design rather than a set of boolean columns:

1. Simply calculate how many categories a product is in, using an SQL `COUNT()`.
2. Store information about the categories themselves in your database, rather than having to bury it somewhere in your application code. As well as the name column suggested in your option B schema, you might want a longer description, or flags for when that category should be displayed, etc
3. Add, remove, or rename a category without having to touch a single line of your application's code.

Again, you may not want to do any of these things **right now**, but unless you plan on throwing away the application in a week's time, **you cannot predict future requirements**. A large part of software design is about making the code maintainable and building in a reasonable compromise between simplicity and flexibility.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I never need to do the things you mentioned in the two bullet points. That's the whole point of asking an optimization question. If this would be subject to change, I obviously would have to go for case B. I don't need to do 1 or 2 or 3 (even though 2 would obviously be "nice").

Comment: I am sure you would agree that there are things that do not change, like the r, g and b in the rgb color system. Those could be my "categories", to give only one example (not the best). I think you are right though, naming them "attributes" rather than "categories" could have made it a little easier to understand.

Comment: This is the only response so far, that actually deals with my question, so +1.

Comment: @Ben I would not personally think of 'r', 'g', and 'b' as "categories"; they are inherent attributes of a single piece of data (they are also not booleans, but I do understand your point, and mentioned "attributes" in my answer). The way your question was worded was that you had a list of, in your anonymised example, 6 named categories which could "contain" your items; this is different from your items having certain intrinsic properties.

Comment: @Ben To give some extremes at either end of the scale, the attribute "is deleted" would clearly not be a "category" that you would put into a mapping table; however, the categories "is waterproof" and "is circular" clearly come from a limitless list of categories which could easily be expanded to contain "is edible", etc, even if initial requirements give a definite list to work with. It's obviously up to you to determine what makes sense in your case, based on just how fundamentally fixed your list of categories is.